# How would I be able to get my GLTF object follow someone using touch on a phone?

Tags: html, three.js

using resources on three.js and from other questions, I have created a GLTF model that follows the mouse when it moves around the canvas (see the codepen below).

However, when viewing the page on my android phone the model will not rotate to follow touches like it would if it was used in OrbitControls. I've tried to understand how to use eventlisteners; touchstart, touchend and touchmove as I think this may be what I need to get it to respond to touch events, but unfortunately I'm not very good at JavaScript and very new to three.js.

A working example (although I have no idea whether they are using three.js) would be on this page: https://garden-eight.com/. The model follows the mouse, and when viewed on mobile follows fingers.

Would anyone be able to lend their expertise please? :)

I'm more than happy to provide more information. I haven't ask many questions on StackOverflow.

https://codepen.io/Beddalla/pen/qGLeyR

```
        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader(); /* Creates a GLTF Loader */


        loader.load( 'https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=https://www.adambeddall.com/monkey.glb', function ( gltf ) { /* Path to model */
            scene.add( gltf.scene ); /* Adds the model to the scene */
            model = gltf.scene
        });

        var plane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), -4);
        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
        var pointOfIntersection = new THREE.Vector3();
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);

        function onMouseMove(event){
          mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
          raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
          raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, pointOfIntersection);
          model.lookAt(pointOfIntersection);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution for this issue is to add an event listener to the `touchmove` event and then use the event data from `event.touches[ 0 ].clientX` and `event.touches[ 0 ].clientY` to compute the respective `mouse` vector.

```
function onTouchMove(event){

    mouse.x = ( event.touches[ 0 ].clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.touches[ 0 ].clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    // rest of your code

}
```

Updated Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VOgwvO

`three.js R105`

Comment: This is great! Very easy to understand and does exactly what I wanted.

Since your answer, I've been looking to try and find a way so that when someone moves the mouse off the page and then back on at a different location the model doesn't jump to the new rotation, but transitions smoothly.

I don't suppose you have encountered this before?

Comment: Um, maybe you can solve this issue by using [Quaternion.rotateTowards()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Quaternion.rotateTowards) instead of `lookAt()`. There is also an official example demonstrating this approach: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_math_orientation_transform

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the links - I'll have to take a look and see if I can understand it haha!

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to get it to work when following the example on three.js. For those interested here is a codepen with where I got to: https://codepen.io/Beddalla/pen/xNvLqY
(Model loaded in, but can't get it to look at the target. Even if I could, I don't know if I would be able to figure out how to get it to look at the mouse/touch)

Tried following these examples: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_bumpmap

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opGErz

I'm disappointed I can't get it to work, but maybe this will help someone in the future. Any help is appreciated.